# Running node.js script from php document and getting output

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am trying to run a node.js script from PHP and getting the output in the PHP.

The only way I could make it work is this but it seems really dodgy.

```
public function test() {
   exec('/usr/bin/node ' . 'test.js', $o);
 
   dd($o);
}
```

```
function test() {
   return 'hello world';
}

console.log(test())
```

What is the best way to achieve this? I'd need to pass parameter to it too and I doubt this is the way to achieve it.

*<sup>It probably doesn't make any difference, but I am using Laravel.</sup>*

Comment: run the node server per se and make a curl request to the node server

Comment: If I install express.js and say npm serve, will I be able to talk port 3000?

Comment: yes. I'd suggest you to use express, configure pm2 to run the node server standalone and make it listen on the port you want (unless you have something else on that port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a "program" from PHP is somewhat complicated, especially if you need it to run with args. Since arguments need to be properly escaped, you have to call [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to prevent problems with passing quotes, file paths including spaces and strings starting with `~` for example.

I would suggest using a dependency - `symfony/process` [Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

I know that responding with a link to a dependency is frowned upon, but handling the possible arguments and/or binary output can be hard, especially on Windows and/or other non-posix systems.

With `symfony/process`, running a `node` script is fairly simple, given that node is in `PATH`

```php
<?php

// Run the composer autoloader
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['node', 'script.js']);
$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

More in-depth usage, including running multiple processes in parallel are included in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

Comment: I agree - returning data is also weird. This approach also needs me to console.log() the data to access right? :( I started thinking setting up express is cleaner approach

Comment: @senty Depends on the precise issue you need to solve. Running a dedicated server is often overkill, but can lead to a more extensible API. If you have control over `script.js` you can try adding a `--json` argument or similar, that will output the data as JSON for the PHP consumer and ouput them as human-readable when the argument is not specified.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it's very valuable. Your answer was the answer the OP so I'm accepting it. I'll go with express and see where it goes. Hopefully I won't have issue with exposing it out.